# appendTo adds html in the wrong place

Tags: jquery, appendto

I have this html:

```
<nav id="services">
<ul>
<li><a href="/uplighting">uplighting</a></li>
<li><a href="/backdrops">illuminated backdrops</a></li>
<li><a href="/monograms">monogram projection</a></li>
<li><a href="/table">table lighting</a></li>
<li><a href="/lanterns">outdoor lanterns</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this jquery:

```
$("#services ul li a").mouseenter(function(){

pop_item_link = $(this).attr('href');

$("<article id=\"pop_item\" href=\"" + pop_item_link + "\"></article>").appendTo("#services");

});
```

which works fine.
But if I use the parent selector instead:

```
$("<article id=\"pop_item\" href=\"" + pop_item_link + "\"></article>").appendTo(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

the html is inserted after the anchor:

```
<nav id="services">
<ul>
<li><a href="/uplighting">uplighting</a></li>
<li><a href="/backdrops">illuminated backdrops</a>
<article id="pop_item" href="/backdrops"></article>
</li>
<li><a href="/monograms">monogram projection</a></li>
<li><a href="/table">table lighting</a></li>
<li><a href="/lanterns">outdoor lanterns</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The same happens using closest()

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I want to avoid using the id selector so I can use the same code for another menu.

Comment: this should be: `.appendTo($(this).closest('nav'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.appendTo(this)` is all that's coming into play and since `this` is `a` that's why it appends to `a`. So when you add `.parent()` you're chaining the method as you would when you're getting ready to manipulate the parent of the matched element.

You want to append to the `nav` as follows:

```
.appendTo( $(this).closest('nav') );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have it as

`.appendTo($(this).parent().parent().parent())`

OR

`.appendTo($(this).closest('nav')`

<sub>*Notice that the `.parent()`s and the `.closest()` are inside `.appendTo()`*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You would want:

- `.appendTo($(this).parent().parent().parent())`

or

- `.appendTo($(this).closest('nav'))`

Comment: I knew it would be something outrageously simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
.appendTo($(this).parentsUntil('nav').parent('nav');
```